# CSS3 for Curve Symbol

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Im  looking for css code for below shape, i have tried using border radius but have to work with different div's for top border and left curve. 
Im looking for css which draws complete shape below. Any help ?

```css
.Curve{
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    width: 50px;
    border: solid 1px #4C5D65;
    height: 86px;
    content: " ";
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(271deg);
    border-color: transparent transparent #4C5D65 transparent;
    border-radius: 0 0 51px 99%/44px;
 }
```

```html
<span class="Curve"> </span>
```

Here is what i have tried
https://jsfiddle.net/sonymax46/wdaLomnf/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea with one element. Simply adjust the gradient until you get what you want.

```css
.curve {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border-top:2px solid;
  background:
    radial-gradient(100% 57% at left,transparent calc(100% - 2px),#000,transparent 100%)
    left/15px 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="curve"></div>
```

Another idea:

```css
.curve {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border-top:2px solid;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.curve:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  border-radius:50%;
  top:calc(50% - 40px);
  right:calc(100% - 12px);
  border:2px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="curve"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change

`border-color: transparent transparent #4C5D65 transparent;` to

`border-color: #4C5D65 transparent #4C5D65 transparent;`

or add an element above, make the margins of both equal to zero, and then make the bottom border the same colour.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```css
.Curve {
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  border: solid 1px #4C5D65;
  height: 86px;
  content: " ";
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(271deg);
  border-color: transparent transparent #4C5D65 transparent;
  border-radius: 0 0 51px 99%/44px;
}

span.Curve:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid #21262D;
  top: 92%;
  left: -6px;
  /* background: rebeccapurple; */
}
```

```html
<span class="Curve"></span>
```

Comment: Note that the `content` property does nothing on `.Curve`. It has to be applied to a pseudo-element selector.